# When using unix pipes (in C) does the OS balance every write() with a read() or does it balance the total number of bytes?

Tags: c, unix, pipe

for example, i want to get an array of 4 ints from child to parent. parent calls

```
read(apipe, buf, sizeof(int)*4);
```

child calls

```
for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
    write(bpipe, &array[i], sizeof(int));
```

does this do what I intend (getting 4 ints to the parent) or does the parent simply get the first integer?

I tried searching for this answer elsewhere, but either I don't know how to search or this is too subtle (or on the other hand too seemingly obvious) for literature to dwell on it much.

EDIT: To clarify further, I was trying to write a 4-part message and read all 4 parts in one read(). See comments on accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` and `write` work with bytes, not messages. For details of how they behave with pipes, see the documentation in POSIX:

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html

In your code, I think the `read` *should* always get 4 ints, due to:

> Upon successful completion, where nbyte is greater than 0, read() shall mark for update the last data access timestamp of the file, and shall return the number of bytes read. This number shall never be greater than nbyte. **The value returned may be less than nbyte** if the number of bytes left in the file is less than nbyte, if the read() request was interrupted by a signal, or **if the file is a pipe or FIFO or special file and has fewer than nbyte bytes immediately available for reading**. For example, a read() from a file associated with a terminal may return one typed line of data.

There will always be 4 ints available for reading, because `4*sizeof(int) < PIPE_BUF` and thus writes of this size are atomic.

It's possible that the allowance for `read` to return a short read when interrupted by a signal could come into play, but that should not be able to happen (in the real world, at least) when sufficiently many bytes are available immediately.

Comment: maybe that my brain is fried from working on this, but I'm reaching a different conclusion from reading the text. The way I understand it, right after the first write in the loop, the read can go through with the one int in the buffer, since *value returned (i.e. read) may be less then nbytes*. So as I see it, nbytes = sizeof(int)*4 but read would read the 1-int buffer and return sizeof(int)... cont.

Comment: At least that's what seems to be happening to me. So the conclusion I draw from the text is that writes need to be atomic if possible, but you can have multiple reads for every write. Does that make sense or am I missing something?

Comment: The writes will be atomic. You can perform multiple reads if you prefer, and to be safe you might want to loop reading into the remainder of the buffer (up to the total number of desired bytes) if the read returns a short read. However, I think in the real world you'll be unable to construct a situation where a 16-byte read from a pipe fails to be atomic when all the writes to that pipe are 16-byte, simply because the situations that lead to "reads of fewer than nbytes" simply do not arise.

Comment: oddly enough such a situation seems to be arising here lol. why this is so may remain a mystery to me for now. i used the loop to full up an output buffer array[4] and flush it all down with a single write instead of running write() 4 times in the loop and this seems to have fixed all my problems.

Comment: D'oh, I misread your question and didn't realize you were writing the message in parts. Of course that can cause short reads due to timing issues. Writing the whole message atomically is what you want to do.

Comment: Sounds like the pipe is non-blocking.  You would have gotten all four in one `read` _if_ all the `write`s had already finished.  There are ways to deal with this while still using multiple writes but they complicate things, so if you can just use a single write that's easier.

Comment: There are four separate write calls; they might not all be complete when the read is issued, in which case, the read will return with the data that is available.  Each write is itself atomic; there's no question of getting 3 of 4 bytes from one of the `sizeof(int)` writes (assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4).  But you're not guaranteed all `4*sizeof(int)` in a single `read()` if (meaning 'when') the timing is just exactly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The [Definitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html) section of POSIX says that a pipe is identical to a FIFO except it has no entry in the file system.

From the POSIX definition for [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html):

> Write requests to a pipe or FIFO shall be handled in the same way as a regular file with the following exceptions:
>
> - There is no file offset associated with a pipe, hence each write request shall append to the end of the pipe.
> - Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less shall not be interleaved with data from other processes doing writes on the same pipe. Writes of greater than {PIPE_BUF} bytes may have data interleaved, on arbitrary boundaries, with writes by other processes, whether or not the O_NONBLOCK flag of the file status flags is set.

From the POSIX definition for [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html):

> The value returned may be less than nbyte if the number of bytes left in the file is less than nbyte, if the read() request was interrupted by a signal, or if the file is a pipe or FIFO or special file and has fewer than nbyte bytes immediately available for reading.

Later, in the informative (non-normative) section of `read()` entry, it says:

> The standard developers considered adding atomicity requirements to a pipe or FIFO, but recognized that due to the nature of pipes and FIFOs there could be no guarantee of atomicity of reads of {PIPE_BUF} or any other size that would be an aid to applications portability.

---

So, the standard implies that if all `4*sizeof(int)` bytes are available when the `read()` is issued, then all `4*sizeof(int)` bytes will be returned, but if only 1, 2 or 3 of the `write()` calls have completed, then the `read()` will not wait for the fourth to finish; it will return with a short read.

Consequently, your reading code must allow for 'short reads' which are non-erroneous; they simply mean that not all the required data was present.

Answer (score 0):

It should read all four.  If it doesn't, the error from `read` should indicate why.  The number of writes and reads doesn't need to match.